# memory allocation in small memory devices

Tags: memory, symbian

Some systems such as Symbian insist people to use heap instead of stack when allocating
big objects(such as pathnames, which may be more than 512 bytes). Is there any specific reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most embedded devices doesn't come with a memory management unit so there is no way for the OS to grow the stack space automatically, transparent to the programmer. Even assuming a growable stack, you will have to manage it yourself which is no better than heap allocation and defeats the purpose of using a stack in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the stack on an embedded device is fixed to be quite small i.e. 8K is the default stack size on Symbian.

If you consider a maximum length filename is 256bytes, but double that for unicode that's 512bytes already (1/16th of your whole stack) just for 1 filename. So you can imagine that it is quite easy to use up the stack if you're not careful.

Answer (score 3):

Most Symbian devices do come with an MMU, but, until very recently, do not support paging. This means that physical RAM is committed for every running process. Each thread on Symbian has (usually) a fixed 8KB stack. If each thread has a stack, then increasing the size of this stack from 8KB to, say 32KB, would have a large impact on the memory requirements of the device.

The heap is global. Increasing its size, if you need to do so, has far less impact. So, on Symbian, the stack is for small data items only - allocate larger ones from the heap.

Answer (score 2):

Embedded devices often have a fixed-sized stack. Since a subroutine call in C only needs to push a few words onto the stack, a few hundred byte may suffice (if you avoid recursive function calls).

Answer (score 0):

The stack for embedded devices usually resides in a very small amount of high-speed memory. If you allocate large objects on the stack on such a device, you might be facing a **stack overflow**.

Comment: You mean to say that stacks are generally allocated in cache?